# The import org.apache.commons.net cannot be resolved - Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, apache, import, libraries, eclipse-juno

Good morning:

I have a terrible problem with my Eclipse Juno.

Due to I had to format my computer, I lost the configuration of my Eclipse Juno.

I am trying to work again with my new Eclipse Juno configured, but I think something is missing.

My problem is, I import a Java Project that HAS NO ERROR some weeks ago, and I am 100 % sure about that.

Now, the project has errors like:

**The import javax.mail cannot be resolver
The import org.apache.commons.net cannot be resolved
TimeStamp cannot be resolver to a type
**

Of course, I tried all.

I cleaned the project.
I tried to remove and add again all the libraries I got in the java build path.
I tried to switch from jre6 to jre7.
I tried to change the Target Platform...

Nothing worked!! I am desperate!

[image]

Can anyone help me?

PS: I have the tomcat 5.5 installed in Eclipse Juno also.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Calm yourself. The problem is simply that your project need some additional libraries to be compiled. By the errors you showed, you need at least these:

- javamail.jar
- commons-net.jar

They are both open source libraries and you will find them with a bit of googling.

Why before formatting everything worked fine, and now it doesn't anymore? Surely you had these libraries in some other place outside your project. For example, within the bundled libraries of Tomcat.

Comment: I was sure that they were inside the project. We worked with Internal Libraries, not external. Anyway, I solved the problem this weekend adding more libraries. Thanks a lot Little Santi.